# Terminal broken characters

Tags: gnome-terminal, encoding

It doesn't matter if `gnome-terminal` or `xfce4-terminal` is used, I got always some broken characters in my terminal window.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

[image: Terminal screenshot - bigger font]

Specs:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Ubuntu Mono, UTF-8 encoding
- ZSH

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What locale are you using under Settings -> Language and Support?

Comment: English. Second one is german

Comment: Looks like an escape sequence unrecognized by gnome-terminal, probably ESC k l if I see the screenshot correctly, but could you please increase the font size all the way to the maximum? What's your shell? (Looks like zsh perhaps?) That one seems to output this sequence before executing the command.

Comment: egmont see my updated post.

Comment: Did you notice a pattern for the broken characters? For example does that always happen when running `l`? Maybe seeing the content of `~/.zshrc` could be useful.

Comment: There seems no pattern. The command doesn't matter.

Comment: Yup someone prints ESC k l or ESC k l s. It could easily be your zsh, your zsh prompt or theme or other settings (I'm not familiar with zsh). Check if the problem disappears with bash, in that case it's definitely your zsh configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my build and your question was the only one showing the problem I was having.

I had added the following line to my .zshrc:

```
 export TERM=screen-256color
```

Commenting it out fixed my problem. I unfortunately don't understand the reasons behind the bug, but hoping knowing this is a step in someone else fixing a similar problem.

Comment: Yep, thats solved my problem too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403130

The solution "is practically impossible. The code ... is terribly complicated, I'm afraid to touch it."

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my two cents:
Actually I solved the problem by uncommenting this line in .zshrc:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

It did the trick.