# Windows 10 oh my zsh fonts not working

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, utf-8

I recently did the Windows 10 bash and changed my shell to zsh. When I run the themes my font encoding isn't working. I checked a couple things, installed the powerline fonts and have looked at this: [Terminal broken characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736114/terminal-broken-characters)

I am just seeing a question mark and my bright green color never changes. However, uncommenting out my LANG didn't work. Also, if I run `locale`I see,

```
~ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

[screen shot of my shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOC4H.png)

I just changed to the menlo font, which solved the ? issue, but my color of font is always showing green still.